# Rmarkdown simple website: different horizontal rule styles on the same html document

Tags: html, css, r-markdown

I edited my question and completed it with a reproducible example.

When I create a standalone RMarkdown with `output: html_document` and try to implement different styles of horizontal rules via css (like described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_style_hr.asp)) called from an external `.css` file, I successfully control the styles of the horizontal rules.

For example, when you knit the following `.Rmd`:

```
---
output: html_document
css:"test.css"
---
This line is supposed to be solid red :
<hr class="new1">

This line is supposed to be dashed red:
<hr class="new2">
```

With the file `test.css` like so:

```
/* Red border */
hr.new1 {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

/* Dashed red border */
hr.new2 {
  border-top: 1px dashed red;
}
```

But when I try to produce the same lines in an Rmarkdown simple website (created via "Create project">"New directory">"Simple RMarkdown website") by having an external `.css` that I call from the `.yaml` file (see example below), it produces no effect, the horizontal rules are the default ones.

For example, when I click "Build website" with any page of the website being an `.rmd`like follows:

```
---
---
This line is supposed to be solid red :
<hr class="new1">

This line is supposed to be dashed red:
<hr class="new2">
```

With the `_site.yaml` being:

```
name: "my-website"
navbar:
  title: "My Website"
  left:
    - text: "Home"
      href: index.html
    - text: "About"
      href: about.html
      
css: "test.css"
```

and the file `test.css` exactly identical to the previous example (withstandalone html output instead of website); the styles are not applied to the horizontal rules (they are the same as default `<hr>`).

My question is therefore: how can I consistently apply different styles of horizontal rules on all pages of an Rmarkdown simple website by specifying in an external `.css` file ?

I noticed that by adding a css chunk on any page of the website, styles are applied correctly. However, it is not very practical to have to specify this on each page when the external `.css` file is exactly supposed to avoid this and ensure consistent styles for the whole website.

Thank you !

Comment: You should show us a short example of a page from your website with two rules on it, and maybe someone will tell you how to modify it to make one of them thicker or thinner.